# PHP Composer with FPM config

Tags: php, mongodb, composer-php, fpm

When I try to install MongoDB with composer, it complains that I don't have the mongodb extension configured in my ini files. It's looking at the regular php ini files but mine are under `/fpm` as I'm using nginx. How can I tell composer to use the FPM version of PHP?

Comment: Composer is a command-line application. It doesn't use your web server.

Comment: so composer is only for the development environment?

Comment: Would this be a sensible solution: http://paulwhippconsulting.com/blog/getting-php-cli-to-match-php5-fpm-so-it-behaves-consistently-under-nginx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions:
(after I figured out that composer uses the `php-cli` configuration)

1. Link the `php-fpm` configuration into the `php-cli` configuration, as detailed in:

http://paulwhippconsulting.com/blog/getting-php-cli-to-match-php5-fpm-so-it-behaves-consistently-under-nginx/

This seems more elegant, but doesn't seem to be *official* so it may break.

2. Copy all your configuration directives (.ini files) to **both** the `php-cli` and the `php-fpm` configuration directories.

The downside of this ofcourse is that if not done carefully, your production and development environment end up having different configuration settings.